# Nuxt FingerprintJS Module Server and Client solution?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, vue.js, nuxt.js

I using fingerprintJS in NuxtJS+Firebase Projects VuexStore.

When i call that function in client side can get Visitor ID. But i cant get if i use in server side like a nuxtServerInit.

```
  const fpPromise = FingerprintJS.load();
            const abc = (async() => {
                const fp = await fpPromise
                const result = await fp.get()
                const visitorId = result.visitorId
                return visitorId;
            })()
            abc.then(
                function(value) {
                    state.visitorId = value
                },
                function(error) {
                    return error
                }
            )
```

is there a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

From the [NuxtJS documentation](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/concepts/server-side-rendering#server-vs-browser-environments) (about server rendering):

> Because you are in a Node.js environment you have access to Node.js
> objects such as req and res. You do not have access to the window or
> document objects as they belong to the browser environment. You can
> however use window or document by using the beforeMount or mounted
> hooks.

FingerprintJS depends heavily (example [here](https://github.com/fingerprintjs/fingerprintjs/blob/master/src/sources/canvas.ts#L26)) on the browser (hence browser fingerprinting). That means it needs e.g. `window` object which is not available in the server-side rendering context.

I'm not very experienced with NuxtJS, however, [according to the documentation](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/concepts/server-side-rendering#window-or-document-undefined), you should add your fingerprinting code to the `.vue` file like

```
if (process.client) {
  require('external_library')
}
```

Good luck!